# Decrease lives when a player dies

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm working on a mini-game that requires lives. I set up the scoreboards that show the lives on the sidebar, as shown here -[image]

I  set up that board by adding a deathcount objective and then dummied it by adding a dummy objective for it that replaces it on the sidebar. I want to find out how to made that number decrease for any player that has died. Also I would like to how to put a player into spectator mode a player reaches zero "lives."

These are the scoreboard commands (in order) that sets them up.

```
scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount
scoreboard objectives add Lives dummy
scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar Lives
scoreboard players set @a Lives 5
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add the lives count objective (for display) and the death count objective (for behind the scenes):

```
/scoreboard objectives add lives dummy Lives
/scoreboard objectives add deaths Deathcount
```

Then wire these up to a redstone clock:

```
/scoreboard scoreboard players set * lives 5
/scoreboard players operation @a lives -= @a deaths
/gamemode 3 @a[score_deaths_min=5]
/scoreboard players set @a[playerGameType=3] deaths 0
```

Make sure the first two lines are executed in that order, otherwise players will always have what looks like 5 lives.
<sub>Note: I have not tested this, so there are probably some bugs in it.</sub>

Lives will then be the number of lives remaining, which you can display wherever you want to.

Comment: Why do I have to wire /scoreboard scoreboard players set * lives 5 to a clock? Wouldn't that keep giving lives to the player?

Comment: @TechnoSlamm Yes, but then it immediately goes back down because of the next line

Comment: I tried it and still having trouble. Thanks for replying though!

Comment: @TechnoSlamm What troubles are you having?

Comment: It doesn't work...

Comment: @TechnoSlamm In what way does it not work?